# Location directive for Nginx not being observed

Tags: nginx

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is working great with the nginx configuration pasted below. The problem is, I'm trying to add a new url `http://www.example.com/gpp` that will point to a completely directory path/app on the server. Here's my configuration:

```
upstream fi {
        server unix:/media/apps/example/shared/tmp/pids/thin.0.sock;
        server unix:/media/apps/example/shared/tmp/pids/thin.1.sock;
        server unix:/media/apps/example/shared/tmp/pids/thin.2.sock;
        server unix:/media/apps/example/shared/tmp/pids/thin.3.sock;
}

server {

  listen 80;
  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_types application/json text/css application/x-javascript;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  sendfile on;

  keepalive_timeout 65;
  client_max_body_size 2m;

  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;

  #root /media/apps/example/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
  }  


  location / {
    root /media/apps/example/current/public;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
    send_timeout 3600;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
     proxy_pass http://fi;
     break;
    }
  }

  location /gpp {
      alias /media/apps/podcast;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
  }

}
```

Whenever I visit `http://www.example.com/gpp` it just goes to the Rails app listed in `location /` instead of the PHP app I have running in `/media/apps/podcast`. I also tried changing the `alias` directive to `root` but that doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: What happens if you change /gpp to /gpp/ and go to `http://www.example.com/gpp/`? It seems like index directive only works for paths ending in /

Comment: Adding the forward slash in the conf still gives the same results unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure the configuration provided is one you are testing? That is, make sure you've reloaded configuration after editing it, and the reload was successful - make sure there are no errors in the error log. Please also make sure to clear browser cache if you are testing with browser (or, better yet, test with telnet/nc/curl/whatever).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `location` directive for your `/media/apps/podcast` alias. I think this

```
location /gpp {
  alias /media/apps/podcast;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

should just be

```
location /gpp {
  root /media/apps/podcast;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
location /podcast {
    root        /media/apps/;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/podcast/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files      $uri =404;
        root           /media/apps/;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~* ^/podcast/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root    /media/apps/;
    }
}

location /gpp {
    rewrite ^/* /podcast last;
}
```